# Glide Error "cannot find symbol class GlideApp" while creating realm class extending RealmObject

Tags: android, realm, android-glide

I am facing a strange issue with the Glide library, when I create the realm object,
getting the error in Glide library "cannot find symbol class GlideApp". Please help me to solve this issue. There is another post related to the same issue, but it is not answered.

[Unable to generate GlideApp & Glide Requests when using Realm Database in my project in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566936/unable-to-generate-glideapp-glide-requests-when-using-realm-database-in-my-pro)

```
Glide:
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

Realm:
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.2"
```

Comment: Can you add you gradle file?

Comment: @VivekSasidharan added Gradle code.

Comment: try with `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'`

Comment: @nkar Are you using Kotlin or Java?

Comment: @VivekSasidharan using Java.

Comment: Can you post your full gradle file? I tried creating a new project with Glide & Realm and it is working as expected!

Comment: @VivekSasidharan Thanks For the reply. Changed RequestOptions to BaseRequestOptions<?>  in glideOption extended class. It solved the issue.